# Pervasive PSQL 10 - Update an DDF

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm using Pervasive PSQL Server 10 and I need to update my DDF-Files, because some components have problems accessing to a database, which was created with an previous version.

The DDFBuilder also says: "Scalable SQL v3.00 data dictionary files (DDFs) were detected. DDFBuilder does not support operations with v3.00 DDFs. Please convert the DDFs to V4.00 using Pervasive's Scalable SQL v4.00 DDF Conversion Utility."

There is no such Utility on the website of Pervasive. It seems it was part of PSQL 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option you have is to create a new set of DDFs and use those.  You can create a new, empty set of DDFs by creating a PSQL database pointing to directory without DDFs.
You will need to recreate the table entries in the new DDFs.
My suggestion is to create the DDFs in a new directory, back up the old DDFs, copy the new DDFs to the directory where the old DDFs were, then create new table entries either using CREATE TABLE statements or DDF Builder.

Comment: That is a good idea but it would result in loosing all table and field definitions for the whole database. Is there no conversion utility to convert the existing files?

Comment: Yes, you would lose all definitions and would need to recreate them.  There is no utility to convert the files.  Scalable SQL 3.0 (that originally created the files) was released in 1995 and Scalable SQL v4.0 (with the updated DDF format) was released in 1997.  The only conversion tool used the Scalable SQL API which was dropped in PSQL 2000.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems I have to develop a program which exports all existing definitions to the DDF Builder XML-Format and import them one by one. Writing Definitions for hundreds of tables without making any fault would be an suicide mission. Viva la closed Source! -_-

Comment: I don't have any old DDFs to test with, but you might try opening the database in PCC.  If you can see the tables, you might be able to right click the table name, select Edit then click the "SQL View" tab and get the SQL statement to recreate the table.

Comment: @mirtheil, what is PCC? I have .dat and .idx files can I open them in any database to view the table filed information?

Comment: @elmo PCC is the Pervasive Control Center.  Btrieve / Pervasive files can have any extension but usually only have one extension.